# How does tf.Data Input Pipeline with Data Augmentation every epoch works?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I used this code (https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/outreach/blogs/segmentation_blogpost/image_segmentation.ipynb#scrollTo=tkNqQaR2HQbd) for my data tensorflow pipeline. But I don't understand how it works. They are telling that "During training time, our model would never see twice the exact same picture". But how does this work? I only use tf.data Map-Function with _augment-Function once. Does this happen every step at my model.fit Function?

I tried to verify my _augment function with printing out something. But this will only occur at the first time and not every epoch.

```py
def get_baseline_dataset(filenames, 
                         labels,
                         preproc_fn=functools.partial(_augment),
                         threads=5, 
                         batch_size=batch_size,
                         shuffle=True):           
  num_x = len(filenames)
  # Create a dataset from the filenames and labels
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
  # Map our preprocessing function to every element in our dataset, taking
  # advantage of multithreading
  dataset = dataset.map(_process_pathnames, num_parallel_calls=threads)
  if preproc_fn.keywords is not None and 'resize' not in preproc_fn.keywords:
    assert batch_size == 1, "Batching images must be of the same size"

  dataset = dataset.map(preproc_fn, num_parallel_calls=threads)

  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(num_x)


  # It's necessary to repeat our data for all epochs 
  dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
  return dataset
```

```py
tr_cfg = {
    'resize': [img_shape[0], img_shape[1]],
    'scale': 1 / 255.,
    'hue_delta': 0.1,
    'horizontal_flip': True,
    'width_shift_range': 0.1,
    'height_shift_range': 0.1
}
tr_preprocessing_fn = functools.partial(_augment, **tr_cfg)
```

```py
train_ds = get_baseline_dataset(x_train_filenames,
                                y_train_filenames,
                                preproc_fn=tr_preprocessing_fn,
                                batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting the essential steps from https://cs230-stanford.github.io/tensorflow-input-data
I suggest you to skim through the article once for details.

"
To summarize, one good order for the different transformations is:

1. create the dataset
2. shuffle (with a big enough buffer size)
3. repeat
4. map with the actual work (preprocessing, augmentation…) using multiple parallel calls.
5. batch
6. prefetch
   "

This should give what you desire because "augmentation" is after "repeat".
Hope it helps.

Comment: that link is dead. This one seems to have similar information https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/datapipeline/#building-an-image-data-pipeline. The exception is that it doesn't use repeat any more. I can't find anything conclusive, but I get the impression that in tf2 repeat() is only useful *before* shuffle(). In that case it would shuffle across epoch boundaries.

Comment: @craq I think the formatting in the summary of the above blog post got a bit messed up. If you look at the order of operations at the end, they in fact have "3 repeat" right after shuffle.